# Как разобрать в Android Profiler , чтобы узнать где утечка?

Tags: java, android, память, cordova

коллеги! В приложение, которое я поддерживаю периодически возникают вылеты. Иногда с ошибкой (система показывает алерт для пользователя), иногда без, но в логах и crashlitic ничего нет. Это привело меня к идеи об утечки памяти. Приложение крошечное, но написано заумно (с использование Cardova - WebView-шная прокладка). Много кода на js, html все очень плохо написано. Я смотрю на распределние памяти, и вижу, что в рабочем режиме оно съедает целых 400 Мбб что я думаю для него очень много.

[image: Утечка памяти]

Я бы очень хотел узнать, в какой месте утечка? WebView часть или java? Подскажите, как правильно работать с Android Profiler?

Comment: Где вы смотрите используемую память,

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler